# Determining the source (cell tower or wi-fi) LocationManager used

Tags: android, wifi, locationmanager, locationlistener

Is there a way to determine which service (cell tower or wi-fi) the `LocationManager` used to to get the Location object that it passes to `LocationListener.onLocationChanged(Location location)`

Answer (score 0):

`Location.getProvider()` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getProvider()

this should give you the information you want.

Comment: Wouldn't that just return either LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER or LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, given that those are the only two String constants related to provider in the LocationManager class? And the those two strings have the values "network" and "gps" respectively. I'm looking to see if I can tell which one of the two 'network' methods the device used

Comment: I guess you're right. But despite making an estimate from the accuracy, I can't help you any further. Good luck on your quest.

Comment: That's what my research has led me to believe :/ Would you happen to know which one (cell or wifi) would be more accurate? Or if there is an order the devices follows when both wifi and cell are available, or does it take into account both sources

Comment: I know WiFi is more accurate for sure. WiFi would usually give an error of maximum 30 meters and cell towers can be up to a few kilometers